# Install Maven in jenkins/blueocean docker container

Tags: maven, docker, jenkins

I have started learning jenkins by using jenkinsci/blueocean docker image. Turns out this image does not have maven installed. I followed [Maven Installation on Jenkins Docker Container](https://dzone.com/articles/dockerizing-jenkins-2-setup-and-using-it-along-wit) link to install maven from a .gz file. It did not work.

Can anybody tell me how to install maven inside jenkinsci/blueocean container.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the exact maven version can be downloaded through here: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.5.0/

Comment: @MostafaHussein Thanks. But I don't know how let jenkins know about that file.

Comment: follow the article and you will find that it needs to run the jenkins again "a new container" with mounting option so you can make jenkins aware of it

Comment: Oh okay. I need to delete the existing container and create a new one. I will try. Thanks.

Comment: @MostafaHussein No Luck. I deleted the existing container. Downloaded .gz file. mapped the volume and added the maven installer in jenkins as per the mentioned URL. Jenkins still says mvn command not found. I manually extracted the .gz file and added maven/bin directory to the path. In the container mvn -v works but jenkins still says mvn command not found.

Comment: Please add your `Dockerfile` here...

Comment: @StephenKing I am not using a custom docker file. I just did `docker pull jenkinsci/blueocean` and trying to use mvn gives me command not found. I installed mvn manually in this docker image. And then in my pipeline script rather than using just `mvn` I gave the full path to mvn `/var/jenkins_home/apache-maven-3.5.0/bin/mvn clean package`. Then it started to work. But when I set MAVEN_HOME in Global Tool Configuration `mvn clean package` gives me mvn command not found  error.

Comment: I'd say this is not really how you should be using Docker (also not inside Jenkins). I suggest that you give your Jenkins access to a docker socket so that it can spin up additional containers. Then (using `agent`) pick a docker image that has `mvn` available inside your pipeline.

Comment: @StephenKing Sure I will try that when I am a bit comfortable with Jenkins. But I am still starting out with Jenkins. So I downloaded the docker image. I even set up a local copy of Jenkins using the war file. I have setup mvn on my laptop using homebrew. But still jenkins is not able to find Maven even after specifying the path in MAVEN_HOME. Any idea why?

Comment: Don't waste time with this. Use your Jenkins from the war file, ensure it has access to the docker socket and then use other docker containers to execute your build steps.

Answer (score 2):

Jenkins Blueocean docker image is based on Alpine Linux (Found this by running `cat /etc/*-release` from inside the image via [Portainer](https://www.portainer.io/)).

Alpine uses apk as the package manager/installer. So

- Console login into the container (shell access). Again, I used Portainer's Console connect feature for this.
- Ran `apk add maven` to install maven. This worked and Jenkins step in workflow script `sh mvn clean install` could execute successfully.

**EDIT** The alternative and much better way would be to use a separate maven docker container as Jenkins agent as suggested in the tutorial documentation [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/tutorials/build-a-java-app-with-maven/#create-your-initial-pipeline-as-a-jenkinsfile):

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        docker {
            image 'maven:3-alpine' 
            args '-v /root/.m2:/root/.m2' 
        }
    }
    stages {
        stage('Build') { 
            steps {
                sh 'mvn -B -DskipTests clean package' 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The jenkins/blueocean image is based on Alpine Linux. You can check this by running

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

inside the container.

To install packages on Alpine Linux you will need to use the *apk* package manager. For example:

```
apk add --no-cache package_name
```

However, to successfully run this you need to access the container as root. This can be achieved by running the command below:

```
docker exec --user root -it container_ID bash
```

You can then install maven  in the jenkins/blueocean container by running the command:

```
apk add --no-cache maven
```